# Facebook plugins not working on content/template pages

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, aurelia

I am quite new to Facebook plugin programming. I am referring the quick start document.

In my web site I have a layout page and few content pages. Only the layout page contains the full html-head-body structure and rest of the content pages contain partial html elements (those can be thought of as templates).

I have put the `FB.init()` script only in layout page, just below the `body` tag:

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'MY-APP-ID',
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v2.3'
    });
};

(function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

and trying to test the integration using the like plugin in one of my content page:

```
                <div class="col-sm-10 fb-like"
                 data-share="true"
                 data-width="450"
                 data-show-faces="true">
```

But I found that it is not working when I put it on content/template pages. Note that I have NOT even found any JavaScript error in browser console in this case. However, the same works when I directly put the same in Layout page.

Please let me know what I am missing here.

P.S.: Same applies for fb login (works on layout but not on template).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the `init` is running before the template has been added to the DOM.  You tagged your question for `aurelia` so I am assuming that you have a view model backing the template.  Consider taking advantage of the life cycle callbacks that are available to you -

`attached` - This callback is called once the template has been rendered and the VM has been attached to it.  Putting your `FB.init()` in here should be sufficient.  You can do this either in the parent or the child depending on your setup.