# Script in Aureliaview not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, aurelia

I am facing a strange issue with Aurelia view.
I am using a script tag in one of my Aurelia view to integrate one of the external JavaScript file to my view. The script is not working on IE, and Firefox, but working fin with Chrome.

I found that the issue is not with the external script, rather any script tag within Aurelia view. Even the simple alert:

```
<template>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('Hi');      
</script>...
```

is not working with Firefox, whereas the same is working on Chrome.

Please let me know if I am missing anything.

**EDIT :**
An alternative way to make this work is to use of `attached()` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29459133/2270340).

Comment: what version of IE and FF were you using?

Comment: FF v 36.0.4
IE v 11.0.9600.x

Answer (score 1):

Proper way to inject `<script>` in Aurelia view is to use `document.createElement('script');` in `attached()` like described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36521405/4958643 or to make custom element like `<script-injector>` as described here http://www.sobell.net/calling-external-javascript-from-within-aurelia-templates/