# Script tag in Aurelia view is not executed

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm adding a simple script block to a simple aurelia view:

```
<template>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    alert('Hello!');
    </script>
</template>
```

The script is never run, even though the view is rendered correctly and I can see that the script block does appear in the DOM.

I have also tried dynamically inserting a script block via the viewModel and also tried with:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://blah"></script>
```

I understand it's not best practice to do this, but I'm trying to integrate a third party widget that will then render an iframe. The alert shown above is just a simple way of the verifying the issue that I'm seeing.

The real life scenario is as follows:

- I make an api call to a third party from my view model.
- The following is returned:

  `<script type='text/javascript' language='JavaScript'` src='https://secure.na1.echosign.com/public/embeddedWidget? ` wid=CBFCIBAA3AAABLblqZhBU33GaMRZ2lMelHKzti7RkanxMP5v- uW_f8CEiKoopNNofJWyXhmE56Su3HTbY*&token=CBNCKBAAHBCAABAARNiZ7Yba0h7dnLaQRBAdTdH9UrJZKryP' />

I need to append this to the DOM and have it execute. I am working around this issue by calling the above url via fetch and then I exec the response, but it seems like a tedious/hacky way of doing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend adapting the solution provided in this answer: [Use JS variable to set the src attribute for <script> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150409/use-js-variable-to-set-the-src-attribute-for-script-tag).

In your VM's `bind` or `attached` method (most likely):

```
let scriptURL = api.getURL();

let scriptElement = document.createElement('script');

scriptElement.src = scriptURL;
scriptElement.onload = () => {
    // do anything you need to do here, or call a VM method
    this.someVMMethod();
};

this.scriptElementInHead = document.querySelector('head').appendChild(scriptElement);
```

If need be, you can even remove the script element by keeping a reference to it and removing it from the head element when the component is being unloaded in the `unbind` or `detached` methods.

```
 detached() {
   document.querySelector('head').removeChild(this.scriptElementInHead);
 }
```

Comment: The above indeed work for the simple alert example, so thanks very much - I'd still like to understand why a script tag present in the DOM is not executed though! However, when I try using the third party widget, it does not work. I suspect that the reason for this is that the script returned from the third party is as follows:

document.write('<iframe src="blah" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>');

I suspect this is more of a general document.write issue than the script tag one.

Comment: As I suspected, I've just tracked down this error:

embeddedWidget?wid=CBFrJZ5QxKH5Ybg4ZRieHjGEJ_TbgQ7K…:1Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.

This error was not shown when using the activate method, but was shown when I attached the load to a button.

The issue I had was not an issue with Aurelia, more the implementation of the 3rd party widget when loaded async. I will mark your answer as accepted as it would work in most scenarios.